# How to handle multiple environments in React Native CLI (specific case)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to handle different environments by letting the developers select which one they want to.

So basically lets say we have a login screen and a "Settings" touchable there. When the user press it, or shake the device, the following modal opens:

[image]

I wanna let the user change the environment mode and then restart the application with the selected environment settings.

**.env.development**

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://development-api.io/api
```

**.env.staging**

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://staging-api.io/api
```

**.env.production**

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://production-api.io/api
```

I'm not sure if this is feasable, but my starting point is to try it with react-native-config and react-native-restart. Any thoughts on the best way to do it?

Thank you!

Obs: React Native CLI

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with "restarting apps" but it seems that [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-restart) should do the stuff.

Concerning the "parameter change" before restarting app, it seems for me that you should use a combination of react-redux & persisted store.

Here is the way I would do :

- Set up a persisted Store with an 'ENV' variable in it.

After App start :

- Select option on modal (ask user wether it wants to change 'ENV' value or not if it is already set):
- Send selected value to persisted store, update 'ENV' variable in it.
- Whenever 'ENV' variable is updated : restart App (will restart with persisted ENV value)
- In the root of your app you'll be able to know you 'ENV' Value and proceed consequently using react-native-config.

Hope I've been clear enough, feel free to ask if not